# Unable to convert SQL query to linq query which contains subquery and need to handle two tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, subquery, sql-to-linq-conversion

We are converting a SQL query to a linq query, this conversion is involving two tables as follows:

```
select * 
from Tbl_Vulpith_Registration 
where Profile_Pic is not null 
  and MemId IN (select MemId from Tbl_List_Services)
```

`Tbl_Vulpith_Registration` and `Tbl_List_Services` are the two tables involved.

`memId` is the common column in the both the tables.

This is what we tried to convert the above SQL query to linq:

```
  var reglist = objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.Select(a => a).Where(a => a.Profile_Pic != null);
    var listmemsmemIds = objentity.Tbl_List_Services.Select(b => b.MemId).ToList();

    var finalist = reglist.Select(b => b).Where(c => c.MemId.Contains(listmemsmemIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `MemId` is a numeric type, if so, then you are using [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) wrong, correct your last statement to:

```
var finalist = reglist.Select(b => b).Where(c => listmemsmemIds.Contains(c.MemId));
```

Or even better, use the query syntax, it will get your result in one statement:

```
var finalist = (from a in objentity.Tbl_Vulpith_Registration
                 where a.Profile_Pic != null && (from b in objentity.Tbl_List_Services select b.MemId).Contains(a.MemId)
                 select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(from r in Tbl_Vulpith_Registration.Where(r => r.Profile_Pic != null)
from s in Tbl_List_Services.Where(s => s.MemId == r.MemId)
select r).ToList();
```

I believe you could also use this approach where you join these tables on the common MemId column.